# TFS: Working on new feature but want to retain changes that is not ready for check-in

Tags: tfs

I have made some changes, Feature A that is done shelved and sent for code review.
While Feature A is being reviewed, I want to start working on Feature B, at the same time, I wish to have the changes Feature A available when I'm  working on Feature B.
Once Feature A is done being reviewed (it can be during the development of Feature B), I want to check-in Feature A and Feature B separately.

I thought of:

- Finish Feature A > shelve (and preserve locally) > review.
- Then start Feature B (with Feature A changes) > check-in Feature A from shelve > finish Feature B > shelve(will it detect changes of Feature A as part of the pending changes here?) > review > check-in Feature B changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my workflow now is to shelve Feature B and remove the changes from local before checkin Feature A changes.
Once checkin, Feature B gets unshelved and life goes on.